# Should users do a sprint to answer unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Just like everyone here, I really enjoy this site and would like to see it even better.  I have seen a lot of questions on "meta" concerning the unanswered question.  Many people suggest that theses questions get closed or removed but how does one decide to close or remove a question.

**Coming back with an old proposition**

Since this is a community driven site, maybe the users should have an official "Answer unanswered questions day" where all users who like this site will go around their preferred tags and do a bit of cleanup.  Tags some questions or answer them, it doesn't matter but at least, it would be nice to see the count go down.
EDIT: I know this has already been proposed in 2011 but I would be curious to see what is the people's opinion on it 2 years later, now that it indicates 1,179,164 unanswered questions in SO.

**What's in it for me ?**

A lot of those unanswered questions have been asked a few years ago by a user with a reputation of "1".  Meaning, they will never accept the answer and have most likely lost their credentials.  It would be nice if there could be a system on such a day where users can accept answers that were posted by inactive users more than x days ago.  This way, we could, not only clean up a little bit of the site but also earn some points to do so.

**This has already been proposed**

As someone noted, this has already been proposed.  This is why I added the "What's in it for me?" section that try to bring a solution to some of the answers on that original post.

I guess that's it, just wanted to submit (yet another) suggestion about the unanswered questions.

Comment: What's in it for you is usually not having to compete with others at the same time. Then again, most of the OPs in unanswered are dead if you're after an accept